# limiting profiles to user groups

Tags: control-panel, user-profile, permissions

Can profile fields be limited to user groups in backend? It seems that if you want required front end fields for users registering then admins in backend have to have these as compulsory when creating admin accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Custom fields are attached to Users, not User Groups.

Seems like you'd be able to do what you want on the template side, though.  i.e. something like "if user is in group A, show field B, otherwise hide it".

Or perhaps something like the [Reasons plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft) is the way to go, which adds conditionals to fields/field layouts.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Its not a front end issue as such since i want to create admins and not have to fill out the user fields for the admins. If i switch front end registration to javascript only validation of form then I could get around it - but i am committed to server side validation now ;)

Comment: Ahh... sounds like it's time for a custom plugin, then. :)

Comment: Getting my plugin stripes just now...but how would you go about limiting user profiles to non admin groups?
WHat hook am I after?